# How to remember checked checkboxes in a dynamically generated table with PHP

Tags: php, html, cookies, html-table

I have a PHP file that creates dynamically a html table. The first column has checkboxes, is there any way that I can save the selected checkboxes, so when the user come to the page again in other moment he can push a button and load the old selection?

Can this be done using cookies? Is better to create a file with the selection, give the user the option to download this file, and give to option to upload the file later to refresh the previous selection?

Any other guidance will be really appreciated.

Comment: Depends on how 'permanent' you want the save to be. You could throw it in the users session $_SESSION or cookie or save it to a database.

Comment: There are a number of options: cookie storage, POST+database, AJAX+POST+database, etc. If you post your code, we can provide specific help.

Comment: It depends on how long you wawnt to keep these checkboxes options, if kept in cookies, a user might end up emptying their browser cookies. The best option is saving them into a database. At least, this will last longer than cookies

Answer (score 0):

Here is just a suggestion. Encode the checkboxes into a binary string like 10101000100, keep it in a cookie when the user posts the form (or even onClick events to update the cookie). Also maybe there could be a "code" on the page the user can copy, and paste into a box to restore the selection. Maybe you can convert the binary string to hex to make it look less "binary" :P